# My German Shorthaired Pointer is displaying nervousness and anxiety: what can I do?

Tags: dogs, anxiety, stress

My German Shorthaired Pointer is having issues since our entire family has moved to a new home and yard. She never tore up anything in our house when we would leave her alone, but ever since we moved she appears very nervous, whines and seems to have anxiety.

I need some help trying to figure out what I can do for her. I work about 9 hours a day away from home but she is by my side the minute I get home.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to reduce the stress on her?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

anxiety and unease is very common in dogs after stressful events like moving. Think about it, it must be scary to move to a completely new place with zero explanation!

The best thing you can do to help her out is to exercise her, a lot. A tired dog won't have the energy to be stressed out. Take her for a walk/run before you leave for work, and again when you get home. If your family is home during the day, have them take her out too.

For the time when you're gone, make sure she has a safe space to go to. Open kennels work great for this, especially if you put one of your dirty tee shirts in it. Your smell will be very reassuring to her.

Another thing to try is to leave the tv or music on while you're gone. It sounds weird, but if you always have some sort of noise playing while you're home, your dog will associate that with being around you. Having that noise play (softly) may reassure her while you're gone. It works for my dog, anyways.